# How to deal with the data received from python program

Tags: python, c, sockets

I wrote a C client receiving PDF file from a python server. I think it's easy at first. However ,there are some problem here. The PDF file that received and stored is weird. The followings are some key part of programs (omitted some trivial details).

server.py

```
fp = open(filename,'rb')
content = str(fp.read())
connectionSocket.send(content.encode())
fp.close()
```

client.c

```
int main(void){
    char content[filesize];    //have already gotten the content size
    recvContent(sock, content, filesize);  //recvContent is a function that receive given length data from socket
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename,"wb");    // already get the file name
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= filesize){
        fputc(content[j],fp);
        j++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
int recvContent(SOCKET sock, void * content, int size){
    int recvLen=0;
    int count=0;
    void * startb = content;
    while (count < size) {
        recvLen = recv(sock, (char *)startb,1024, 0);
        startb += recvLen;
        count  += recvLen;
        if (recvLen == SOCKET_ERROR) 
            closeSocket(sock);
    } 
    return count; 
}
```

When I open the received PDF file, it says it's broken. When I open it by a notebook program. Some contents are below.

```
%PDF-1.7\n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\n1 0 obj\n<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 75/Height 75/Length 273/ColorSpace[/Indexed/DeviceRGB 1(\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff)].....(omitted here ).......1]/CropBox[0 0 609.44 394.01]/Resources<</XObject<</Xi0 1 0 R/Xi4 25 0 R/Xi5 26 0 R>>/Font<</FXF20 14 0 R/FXF21 15 0 R/Xi1 2 0 R/Xi2 3 0 R/Xi3 4 0 \n%iText-5.5.10\nstartxref\n35132\n%%EOF\n
```

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please provide a full working example, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have encoded the content on server side, so what you receive is encoded.  You need to decode it before saving to a file.

Comment: Replace `"\\xab"` with `"\xab"`, replace `"\\n"` with `"\r\n"` and so on.